# Is this a safe way to generate new threads and terminate them?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an application that receives alerts from other applications, usually once a minute or so but I need to be able to handle higher volume per minute. The interface I am using, and the Alert framework in general, requires that alerts may be processed asynchronously and can be stopped if they are being processed asynchronously. The stop method specifically is documented as stopping a thread. I wrote the code below to create an AlertRunner thread and then stop the thread. However, is this a proper way to handle terminating a thread? And will this code be able to scale easily (not to a ridiculous volume, but maybe an alert a second or multiple alerts at the same time)?

```
private AlertRunner alertRunner;

@Override
public void receive(Alert a) {
    assert a != null;
    alertRunner = new alertRunner(a.getName());
    a.start();
}

@Override
public void stop(boolean synchronous) {
    if(!synchronous) {
        if(alertRunner != null) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}

class AlertRunner extends Thread {
    private final String alertName;

    public AlertRunner(String alertName) {
        this.alertName = alertName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            log.info("New alert received: " + alertName);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error("Thread interrupted: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` does what you think it does.  What it does is, it will set the _interrupted flag_ in the thread that calls your `stop()` method.  The reason I am suspicious, is that there is seldom any reason for a thread to interrupt itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will not scale easily because `Thread` is quite 'heavy' object. It's expensive to create and it's expensive to start. It's much better to use `ExecutorService` for your task. It will contain a limited number of threads that are ready to process your requests:

```
int threadPoolSize = 5;
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);

public void receive(Alert a) {
    assert a != null;
    executor.submit(() -> {
        // Do your work here
    });
}
```

Here `executor.submit()` will handle your request in a separate thread. If all threads are busy now, the request will wait in a queue, preventing resource exhausting. It also returns an instance of `Future` that you can use to wait for the completion of the handling, setting the timeout, receiving the result, for cancelling execution and many other useful things.

Comment: Thanks that is just what I was looking for! When I cancel the execution does it just cancel the execution of the one alert that should be cancelled?

Comment: Yes, calling `cancel()` on a `Future` cancels the particular task: `Future<?> f = executor.submit(() -> { ... });` and then  `f.cancel(true)`